# How to change detached or persistent entity to transient state?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

What I want to do is:

1. Read entity from database (using hibernate).
2. change single attribute.
3. insert it again as new entry with new Id(primary key).

I have tried to insert detached entity with null id, but still it complains that duplicate key value violates unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

you need add call `flush()` and `evict()`  session  after you read entity from db , and only after do any changes- change field and set id  null. As you didn't do this you entity is still connected to session context. Also check that duplicate key value violates unique constraint exception not connected another unique key.